# Get affected rows value by updating value of the field which already present

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I've got a table

```
ID   |   NAME    |  VALUE  |
----------------------------
 1   |   Test1   |  VALUE1 |
 2   |   Test2   |  VALUE2 |
 3   |   Test3   |  VALUE3 |
 4   |   Test4   |  VALUE4 |
 5   |   Test5   |  VALUE5 |
```

I'm running this query dynamically

```
$query="UPDATE tables SET `VALUE`='VALUE1' WHERE `ID`='1'"
```

Here i'm updating a value which is already stored. This doesn't update the field value. Because of this i can't get affected rows. I'm using PHP

Is there any way to get the affected rows with the above query.

Comment: is ID numeric or string data?  the where id = '1' implies string system should be smart enough to cast one to the other, but the tics around 1 gave me pause.  However your question is answered by trapping for errors in php?  however to answer your question.... YES see -->http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php  Don't use this answer directly however.. it's deprecated.

Comment: if i reset the value of the field the query runs and i'm getting affected_rows as 1. If i try to update a value which already present, the query runs and i'm getting affected_rows as 0.I have tried this on PHPMyadmin too but getting same result

Comment: "affected rows" only counts rows that were changed. If you set the field to the value it already has, it's not counted.

Comment: @Praveen so I'm confused are you saying it's working now?  I don't understand the question/problem now.

Comment: @Barmar then how to update the row...

Comment: to a  value which already exists in the row.

Comment: If it already has the value, then it's already updated.

Comment: To reiterate what @Barmar said: There are no affected rows because you're not changing anything.  Why are you trying to update a row with a value that you already know it has?  Why do you need a count of rows affected when nothing changed?  I feel like there's something you're leaving out here.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff I suspect he's trying to tell whether the update was successful by testing whether affected rows is > 0. But that's not the proper test when the row may already have the new value. Just test whether the query returned true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Your query works according to this SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84beb/1

Answer (score 0):

If you set a field to the value it already has, it's not counted in "affected rows". If you want to know how many rows might have been modified based on the `WHERE` clause, you need to do a separate `SELECT` with the same clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows FROM tables WHERE id = 1;
```